# Recovery of a Samsung SSD T5 Drive

Tags: ssd

I have a Samsung Portable SSD T5 1TB drive which has been partitioned under Windows 10. As of today, I can't access to the drive anymore, as the Samsung Portable SSD Software 1.6.6 tells me "Failed to check free space or failed to locate a volume".

I must say that:

- Device Manager tells me that the Samsung Portable SSD T5 SCSI Disk is present
- Disk Management tells me there are two partitions: a 200 MB partition (Disk 1, Partition 1) with no file system, and a 931.19 GB partition (Disk 2, Partition 2) with no file system. Both show "Healthy" as a status.

[image]

Comment: Does it show in Windows Explorer? If so, right-click on it, go to Properties > Tools > Check and let Windows inspect your drive. It may have to go offline after check, then be brought back online. Could be your drive is infected, too. I suppose you've tried it in a different USB port? What happens if you try to update the SSD driver in Device Manager? EDIT: there's an excellent tool by Samsung called Samsung Magician that could help you diagnose your SSD, update/upgrade its firmware, etc... Here: https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/

Comment: Diagnose with Samsung Magician wouldn't help it - the partion is healthy. The problem is with file system! Updating drivers/firmware may lead to complete data loss!

Comment: You might try reseating the SSD(s). Maybe they aren't getting the right ground or connection. Only do this if you have experienced, otherwise find a friend who knows about the internal  parts of the machine. If you do have experience, cleaning up the CPU fan, etc., while you are there, this may help with other situations, heat, etc.

Comment: @Didier the drive doesn't show in Windows Explorer. Samsung Magician detects the Drive, but doesn't detect the file system unfortunately.

Comment: Does it propose a firmware upgrade/update for this SSD?

Comment: @Didier: no, everything is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like file system on SSD is corrupted.

You can try to recover the files with some of recovery tools, like R-Studio or Recuva.
Attention: using tools you can make data unrecoverable.

If the data on SSD is really important, I’d contact the professional recovery service.
To avoid such situation I highly advise to have periodically backups. For 1TB of data cloud storage can be  an efficient solution (starting from 5USD/1TB monthly depending on provider). More to read here - https://www.vmwareblog.org/single-cloud-enough-secure-backups-5-cool-cross-cloud-solutions-consider/

Comment: Dude, the guy is trying to access data on his SSD, and you are trying to sell him some dopey stuff?

Comment: What staff? If you know the better recovery solution - advise it! I used only Recuva and R-Studio. It helped in some cases. Regarding backups - I haven't mentioned any vendor, and I don't see any problems to recommend doing backups in 2020!

Comment: I don't see any problem either, unless you try to push a specific product or vendor. As for Recuva and other data-recovery software, they only work when you have actual access to the drive. Hence my questions: Is the drive visible in Explorer, and if so, check it with Windows's tool; Is the drive visible in Device Manager (seems so) and try to update its driver. As for Samsung Magician, I'm posting from a Lenovo laptop with a Samsung SSD in it, and I ugraded the firmware just a week ago. Guess what? No data loss. None. Zippo.

Comment: You don't know, what are you talking about. The drive may be visible in Explorer, only if file system is recognized. From device manager - you can see, that file system is missing, so this question is useless. SSD or better to say controller driver doesn't affect the file system below, if it corrupt. Updating firmware shouldn't lead to data loss with healthy drive, but may limit the recoverabilty of currupted one.

Comment: Regarding visibility in Explorer to recover data - the drive shouldn't be visible to use R-Studio or for example Ontrack EasyRecovery or Recuva - https://www.ccleaner.com/docs/recuva/using-recuva/recovering-files-from-damaged-or-reformatted-disks

Comment: Unfortunately, I DO know what I'm talking about, as this is what I do for a living: I deal with that kind of issue, day in, day out, so I've been there, done that, etc... It doesn't HURT to update a driver or upgrade a firmware, even on a drive with an inaccessible partition, but it could help put the drive back online afterwards. Same for trying a file sytem check on the drive in question from Explorer. Worst case scenario, you get an error message saying the drive couldn't be repaired.

Comment: File system check will not work in this case!!! It requires healthy file system. Drivers and firmware updates will not help in this particular case but may hurt (with small probability, but still). Drive is online here.

Comment: Whatever. I'll let the OP be judge of that and decide for him/herself. It's a known and documented issue with Samsung SSDs, both internal and external (https://www.anandtech.com/show/6503/second-update-on-samsung-ssd-840840-pro-failures)...

Comment: The documented issue has completely other symptoms as in OP case – the “which caused the firmware to hang. An SSD obviously can't operate without a functioning firmware so from a user's standpoint, it looked like the drive had completely died ”
The drive doesn’t look as “died” here.

Comment: Doesn't look much alive either, you ask me, but hey, whatever floats your boat, man...

Comment: Thank you all. I think the file system has been somehow corrupted, and I would like to ask again: what is your advice with regard for a professional tool to recover a file system on a SSD drive ? Please suggest software without malware please. What is your experience with Ontrack ? Many thanks.

Comment: You can choose any file/disk recovery tool, which supports damaged file system. To avoid malware, download the applications only from official vendor website. Most recovery tools have trial license, that allows to scan for files on fs without buying it.

I repeat, if data on SSD is really important – search for professional recovery service in your location or country.

Comment: Well noted batistuta09.

Comment: You might want to check this thread here (https://superuser.com/questions/1537792/cant-format-ssd-drive?noredirect=1#comment2334931_1537792), which bears *some* similarities to yours.

Answer (score 0):

As it was written by batistuta09 You can try some of advanced data recovery software (UFS explorer, R-studio, Recuva). Probably You will get some rsults.
You asked about ONTRACK, Yes, they are reputable company in data recovery area.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem with Samsung Portable SSD T5 2TB when I tried Migrate OS to SSD using Diskgenius Free Software. Same "Failed to check free space or failed to locate a volume". I resolved it with registry cure software (I have Avast Cleanup Premium), but you can try other similar software. Problem was with chkdsk check, and it's long time checking and resolving ( depends on your hardware, but it should be 1 hour or more). That solves problem with access to the drive, but it wasn't bootable drive and  it didn't work for me as "Migration OS to SSD".
To avoid this problem  of migrating data from HDD to SSD, try to use Samsung Data Migration software , if you are using Samsung SSD products.