# Can't format SSD drive

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, external-hard-drive, encryption

I have an SSD drive I bought some time ago for using in an old Mac laptop, replacing the slow, spining disk that was inside. Eventually I bought a new laptop and wanted to use this SSD with a case as an external drive. All worked well until one day I tried to format it (or convert it to APFS, or Encrypt it, I'm not sure exactly what happened). Anyway, something happened. No data was lost and I don't care about the data inside but I would like to be able to reuse the disk (after, it's a 1TB SSD).

As it is now:

- I can decrypt it (it was a FileVault drive) and see its contents
- Can't read any file
- Can't write any file

Since then, I've tried everying: Disk Utility first aid, fdisk, format, erase, etc. Tried similar tools things both on macOS and Windows.

I used Crucial's tool that says the hard drive is in good condition so I still have hope.

When I try to erase the whole drive I get:

> "Unable to write to the last block of the device."

Running Disk Utility's First Aid:

> "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.DiskManagement error -69874.)"

Running fsck_hfs searcing for bad blocks and dd to try and reset the whole drive I get:

> "Resource busy" (which should be impossible since no drive is mounted)

I just wanna be able to format this and reuse it.

Comment: Your SSD needs to be visible but offline, i.e. not in use by an OS. Have you tried to download Gparted (here: https://gparted.org/), copy it onto a bootable USB stick, boot from it after plugging the SSD to your PC, and let Gparted wipe it entirely? I've done it countless times on external drives, but never on one that had been formatted on a Mac, so I can't guarantee it'll work. EDIT: once in Gparted, you can format it to your liking, of course. Wiping it doesn't mean "zeroing it out", just erasing the partition table.

Comment: Try [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

Comment: Very probably a bad SATA cable - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136601/error-unable-to-write-to-the-last-block-of-the-device

Comment: @Tetsujin that was my first guess but the cable is fine. Other disks work perfectly with the same enclosure.

Comment: @harrymc testdisk is a fantastic tool but unfortunately it can't do anything about it.

Comment: @Didier Gparted is pretty cool, never heard of it before. It's the closest I get: it recognizes three partitions: a small one in the beginning, a second one that has almost everything and a small one at the end. These seem like the typical partitions of a Mac formatted hard drive. However, it can't write to the disk.

Comment: I'm gonna guess something physical got destroyed when I was messing with it. Or is there still some SSD parameters that I might be ignoring and that might need change?

Comment: There IS a difference between formatting a regular HDD and an SSD: SSDs have a limited lifetime when it comes to read-write cycles, and maybe yours has just reached the end of its life. One thing you can try is what was suggested here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/518722/gparted-cant-create-partition-partition-table) by @diEcho : shutdown your computer, plug your SSD, start your PC with the Gparted USB stick and boot from it, select your SSD in the drop-down on top, right-click on its line and select New > Ext4. Add. Complete operation with the green check icon on top. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 You should get an error message saying the pending operation couldn't be completed. Unplug the SSD, refresh Gparted, plug the SSD again, then right-click on the line of your SSD again, then New > Fat32, and proceed same as you did with ext4. Hopefully, this will turn your SSD from read-only to read-write, and you'll be able to format it with a different file system, be it NTFS or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

f your SSD is write-protected, you will not be able to write any new information on it or change the information stored already.

To remove the write protection, you can use the Diskpart tool by following these steps:

Press the Win+R keys on your keyboard to open the Run box.
Type diskpart -> press Enter to run it.
Inside the diskpart environment -> type and run each of these commands by pressing Enter.
Type list disk -> press Enter.
Identify the SSD in the list -> type select disk X -> press Enter (where X is the name of your SSD).diskpart - SSD drive won't format/SSD format error occured at offset
Run the command attributes disk clear readonly.
Wait for the process to complete -> type Exit and press Enter to close Diskpart.
Try formatting your SSD drive again.

Comment: Tried this but no luck. :(